# Firebase Web Database to Receiveing Data

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am currently working on a project and I'm at the stage of the sign up form. I'm using Firebase for my database and authentication. Currently i can get the user to sign up with email and password and log in to my app. However, I'm currently trying to store the users information into my database when they click the sign up button.

Heres my JS code:

```
//Sign up
function signup(){
  var userEmail = document.getElementById("txtEmail").value; //Email input value
  var userPassword = document.getElementById("txtPassword").value; //Password input value
  var user = firebase.auth().currentUser; //Current user


  <!--Sign up user to app-->
  firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail, userPassword).then(function(user) {
      logUser(user); // call logUser Function if successful
  }, function(error) {
      // Handle Errors here.
      var errorCode = error.code;
      var errorMessage = error.message;
      window.alert("Error: " + error.message);
  });

  function logUser(user) {
      var ref = firebase.database().ref("users"); //database ref
      var obj = {
          "user": user.uid,     //users data to be entered
          "email": user.email
          };
      ref.push(obj);
  }

  //if email is not null redirect page.
  if(userEmail != ''){
      <!----Loads Sign up page according to select drop down list---------->
      var doc = document.getElementById('selectMenu');
      location = doc.options[doc.selectedIndex].value;
      }
  }
```

On my site a user can sign up to as on of two different types of users. Before they sign up they select what type of user they want to sign up as using a  list. After they have filled out the required fields and clicked the sign up button, depending on the option selected on the select list they are redirected to the full sign up sheet where they fill out more details.

The page redirection is handled by the last if statement:

```
//if email is not null redirect page.
  if(userEmail != ''){
      <!----Loads Sign up page according to select drop down list---------->
      var doc = document.getElementById('selectMenu');
      location = doc.options[doc.selectedIndex].value;
      }
  }
```

Without this if statement the data is written to the database fine but no matter where i put it within the signup() function it just stops the data from being written to the database. I just don't understand why. Can anyone help, see the problem? Let me know if you need more detail.

Thanks.

Comment: The Function inside `signUp()` redirects the page without waiting to save the data to firebase due to asynchronous call. There should be an synchronous function for saving the email and then checking if it is not empty.

Comment: There’s is a function outside of that function that checks if the email and password word if not empty. I put that if statement there for testing I should’ve taken it out before posting this post. Even if I put the location change lines of code in the logUser() function it’ll still stop the code from writing to the database. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you want to save the details to firebase and then redirect to another page

Comment: Yes exactly that. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a callback provided after success or error of push function and then pass the redirection line of code in the callback. In that the code will synchronous and it will fire on after pushing the data to the firebase.

```
function logUser(user) {
    var ref = firebase.database().ref("users"); //database ref
    var obj = {
          "user": user.uid,     //users data to be entered
          "email": user.email
          };
    ref.push(obj, () => {
        if(user.email != ''){
            <!----Loads Sign up page according to select drop down list---------->
            var doc = document.getElementById('selectMenu');
            location = doc.options[doc.selectedIndex].value;
        }
    });
}
```

Or you can return promise to synchronize the redirection code inside `then`

```
let logUser = function(user){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var ref = firebase.database().ref("users"); //database ref
        var obj = {
              "user": user.uid,     //users data to be entered
              "email": user.email
        };
        ref.push(obj);
    });
};

logUser.then(() => {
    if(user.email != ''){
        <!----Loads Sign up page according to select drop down list---------->
        var doc = document.getElementById('selectMenu');
        location = doc.options[doc.selectedIndex].value;
    }
})
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you so much. Really helped a lot. (I have marked up your answer but it doesnt show).

Comment: You cannot mark up you can accept it using the right tick below down mark. Have a look at Accepting an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)